# drupal clean url some pages page not found

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a Drupal 6 site. it has clean URL enabled. when I edit a profile it says page not found. but on the link when I add index.php?q=user, it works. but if that is not there I get an error.

after Google search I came to no its something about, clean URL, and apache config. but I cant seem to no what to do from here.

I have check this:
https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which operating system are you using? You probably need to allow the webserver to overwrite.

Here are two examples (for Apache on Fedora and for Wamp server on Windows):

Linux (Centos) - Add the following to /ets/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

If you are using wamp server on windows, you should click the wamp server logo and select 'Apache -> Apache modules -> rewrite_module'

I haven't tried this on other operating systems myself but I guess it's the solution would be similar to this.